# How to kill a script running in the background, but only get the PID of the script when it was run with a certain flag

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process

I can run multiple instances of a bash script in the background and everything is great. I have it setup in such way that some have `-x` as a flag and some not. See:

```
./test.sh &
./test.sh &
./test.sh -x &
./test.sh -x &
```

Now, I want to kill all scripts that were run with the `-x` flag. I always kill scripts running in the background using this:

```bsh
ps -aux | grep -Po "^\S{1,}\s*\K\d*(?=.*test.sh$)" | \
while read -r level
do
   kill $level
done
```

However, `ps -aux` doesn't show any arguments/flags that were given when the script was run. So when using that, I can't only grab the scripts that were run with `-x`. Is there a solution to this? I want to only kill the background scripts that were run with `-x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pkill` command with the `-f` flag.

The command `pkill test.sh` will kill all processes using `test.sh` as the command name. Using the `-f` flag is explained in `man pgrep`, as `pgrep` and `pkill` use similar syntax:

> -f, --full
>
> The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.

However, you need to surround the search pattern with quotes, and escape the `-` of `-x`. So `pkill -f "test.sh \-x"` will kill only the `test.sh` processes that run with the `-x` flag.

Comment: ... or use the `--` end-of-options flag `pkill -f -- "test.sh -x"` ... you could also use pattern `"test.sh[ \t]+-x"` to allow for arbitrary horizontal whitespace

Comment: Good point @steeldriver. I always manage to forget about `--`.

Comment: ... when you think about it, it's kind of odd that `pgrep`/`pkill` don't implement the `-e pattern` thing that regular grep has to disambiguate the pattern from the options

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ps -aF | grep -Po "^\S{1,}\s*\K\d*(?=.*test.sh -x$)"
```